# Cauchy integral and taylor serie

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion, complex-integration, cauchy-integral-formula

I have a question about my attempt to demonstrate the following exercise:

**exercise:**

Let $f$ be analytic in a domain $\Omega$ and for $a \in \Omega$ let

$$
f_n = \sum_{k=1}^n f^{(k)}(a)(z-a)^k, z \in \Omega
$$

so $f_n(z)$ is the nth partial sum of the Taylor expansion around $a$. Show that if $\overline{D}(a,R) \subset \Omega$, then

$$f_n(z) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_\alpha \frac{f(\epsilon)}{(\epsilon-a)^{n+1}} \frac{(\epsilon-a)^{n+1}-(z-a)^{n+1}}{\epsilon-z}d\epsilon$$
$z\in D(a,R)$, where $\alpha(t) = a+Re^{2\pi i t}$

**My proof:**

Note that:
$$
\frac{1}{2\pi i }\int_\alpha \frac{f(\epsilon)}{(\epsilon-a)^{n+1}}\frac{(\epsilon-a)^{n +1}-(z-a)^{n+1}}{\epsilon-z}d\epsilon$$
$$ = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_\alpha \frac{f(\epsilon)}{\epsilon-z} d\epsilon - \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_\alpha \frac{f(\epsilon)(z-a)^{n+1}}{(\epsilon-a)^{n+1}(\epsilon-z)}d\epsilon
$$
but by the Cauchy integral,
$$
= f(z) - \frac{(z-a)^{n+1}}{2\pi i} \int_\alpha \frac{f(\epsilon)}{(\epsilon-a)^{n+1}(\epsilon-a)}
$$
Since $f$ is analytic, consider the taylor sum of $f$ centered at $a$, hence
$$
= f(z) - \frac{(z-a)^{n+1}}{2\pi i} \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k!} f^{( k)}(a) \int_\alpha \frac{(\epsilon-a)^{k-(n+1)}}{\epsilon-a}d\epsilon
$$
considering $g(z) = (z-a)^{k-(n+1)}$, then $g(z)$ is analytic in $\mathbb{C}$, therefore I apply the cauchy integral and I would stay:
$$
= f(z) - (z-a)^{n+1}\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k!} f^{(k)}(a)(z-a)^ {k-(n+1)} = f(z)-f(z) = 0
$$

**my question:**  where did i get wrong? or why did I get to 0?

Comment: Your $g$ functions are not analytic on the whole of $\mathbb{C}$ for $k < n+1$.

Comment: Why? What is special about the function $g$ to have this property?

Comment: For $k < n+1$, $z \mapsto \frac{1}{(z - a)^{n+1 - k}}$ is not holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}$ because it has a pole at $a$.